# Working with the sklearn Boston Housing Dataset: Trying to create dataframe for coefficients

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I've ran the following lines of code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()
print(boston.data.shape) 

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
x.columns = boston.feature_names
y=pd.DataFrame(boston.target)
y.columns=['TARGET']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3,  random_state=101)

model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(x_train,y_train)


print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
len(model.coef_)

Coefficients: 
 [[-8.74917163e-02  5.02793747e-02  2.06785359e-02  3.75457604e+00
  -1.77933846e+01  3.24118660e+00  1.20902568e-02 -1.40965453e+00
   2.63476633e-01 -1.03376395e-02 -9.52633123e-01  6.20783942e-03
  -5.97955998e-01]]
1


coeffecients = pd.DataFrame(data=model.coef_,index=x.columns,columns=['Coefficient'])
```

error msg: 
    Shape of passed values is (13, 1), indices imply (1, 13)

I think the issue is from the length for the array of coefficients being 1. Not sure though.

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? I am not able to duplcate the issue on `0.19.2`. Its already in the form the answer below has converted to.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this happens because your `y_train` is a 2d DataFrame with shape (n_samples, 1).

> coef_ : array, shape (n_features, ) or (n_targets, n_features)
>
> Estimated coefficients for the linear regression problem. If multiple
>   targets are passed during the fit (y 2D), this is a 2D array of shape
>   (n_targets, n_features), while if only one target is passed, this is a
>   1D array of length n_features.

Pass `np.ravel(y_train)` instead or just use `y = pd.Series(boston.target)` may fix this.